# Error de sintaxis sql en base de datos mysql con python 3

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x

En mi proyecto de mysql con python, al tratar de modifcar un campo de la tabla me genera error la secuencia sql y no entiendo por qué. Me acepta el cambio de nombre pero cuando digito el nuevo precio surge el error. El elemento `Cod` es la llave primaria de mi tabla.

Este es mi **código**:

```
sql="update productos set Nombre='"+nombre+"'Precio='"+precio+"' where Cod="+cod    
mysql.connection.query(self, query)
```

Y el **error** que lanza:

> _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'Precio='120' where Cod=1' at
>   line 1")

Comment: intentastes dar un espacio en Precio campo de la tabla

Comment: Creo que tienes un lío con las comillas simples, revisa esto y en especial, precio es un dato numérico? no debería ir sin comillas?

Comment: ok, voy a evaluar.

Comment: hice el cambio de las comillas, ya me acepta el cambio sin error, pero me concatena nombre y precio en un solo campo?

Comment: si amigo ese era el problema comillas y coma que estaba afectando. gracias nuevamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes separar cada campo con una coma, en tu caso quieres actualizar Nombre y Precio, es decir, entre estos dos va una coma.

> NOTA: En el caso de que tu Precio sea un tipo de dato entero, este no debe llevar comillas simples.

```
sql="update productos set Nombre='"+nombre+"', Precio="+precio+" where Cod="+cod+"
```

Comment: correcto asi es. sin discusion, gracias por tu orientacion.

Answer (score 0):

Una sugerencia, la forma en la que estás ejecutando tu query es insegura. Imagina que tu variable `nombre` contenga una sentencia para eliminar una tabla usando un `DROP TABLE`. A esto se le conoce como [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

En vez de ejecutar tu query de esa forma te recomiendo hacerlo usando cursores y parámetros. No estoy seguro de la librería para MySQL que estás usando pero básicamente sería algo como esto:

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(...)
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = '''
    UPDATE productos 
    SET Nombre=%s, Precio=%s 
    WHERE Cod=%s
'''
params = (
    nombre,
    precio,
    cod
)
cursor.execute(query, params)
```

No sólo es más seguro, también es más legible.

Comment: entendido gracias